# How to filter metakey and meta value in phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I would like to query from phpmyadmin every nickname and user_current_package for a given user_id

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJTi2.png)

I tried this but not working

SELECT `nickname` ,`user_current_package`

FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `user_id` = 262

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT `meta_key`,`meta_value`
FROM `wp_usermeta`
WHERE `user_id` = 262
AND (`meta_key`= nickname
OR `meta_key`= 'user_current_package'
)